# How Horizon makes use of stelar-core?

Tags: stellar-core, horizon

[By definition](https://github.com/stellar/go/tree/master/services/horizon/internal/docs/reference) Horizon `acts as the interface between stellar-core and applications`, and [apparently](https://github.com/stellar/go/blob/master/services/horizon/internal/docs/reference/admin.md) it `needs access ... HTTP API that is published by stellar-core`.

Is there a place where this API is documented?

Answer (score 3):

Horizon

- sends data to **Core** via HTTP GET `/tx?blob=<xdr-envelope>`. See the [txsub package](https://github.com/stellar/go/blob/master/services/horizon/internal/txsub/submitter.go#L62) in Horizon.
- imports data from the **Core** DB by a shared DB instance. See [ingest package](https://github.com/stellar/go/tree/master/services/horizon/internal/ingest)

Comment: The documentation is [here](https://www.stellar.org/developers/stellar-core/software/commands.html#http-commands)

Answer (score 2):

Stellar-core’s HTTP interface is documented under the [http-commands](https://www.stellar.org/developers/stellar-core/software/commands.html#http-commands) page in the software guide.