# Do I need to run Stellar-core and horizon to conduct crowdsale?

Tags: stellar-core, horizon

Do I need to run Stellar-core and horizon-server to conduct crowdsale ?
if yes, Why stellar public horizon is not enough for this case (crowdfunding) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The public servers don't give you an SLA and depending on your case you may hit the [rate limits](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/rate-limiting.html):

> In order to provide service stability, Horizon limits the number of requests a client can perform within a one hour window. By default this is set to 3600 requests per hour—an average of one request per second.

Comment: what if I selfhost the horizon but I will use public stellar-core from this list   https://www.stellarbeat.io/nodes ??

Comment: Horizon imports data from Core by shared DB access. A public core instance won't let you access the DB layer. See https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/641/how-horizon-makes-use-of-stelar-core/654#654


There is a docker container that contains Core, Horizon and PostgreSQL to get started: https://hub.docker.com/r/stellar/quickstart/